# Get data out of a database and separate it in different arrays

Tags: php, mysql, loops, mysqli

I'm trying to get the IP out of the database and split them in different arrays so I can count the amount of clients in every country, and put them in a europe map chart.

Now I am stuck on the part where I split the countries into different arrays.

```
    $result_ip = $dbhandle->query("SELECT ip FROM email;");
    $row_cnt_ip = $result_ip->num_rows;

    $NL = array('');
    $AL = array('');
    $NO_EU = array('');


    $ip = $result_ip;
    $details = json_decode(file_get_contents("http://ipinfo.io/{$ip}"));

    while($r = $details->country->fetch_array(MYSQLI_ASSOC)):
       for($i = 1; $i < $row_cnt_ip; $i++) {
    switch ($details->country) {
        case "NL": //Netherlands
          array_push($NL,"$details->country");
            break;
        case "AL":  //Albania
            array_push($AL,"$details->country");
            break;
        default;
             array_push($NO_EU,"$details->country");
            break;
          }
         }
        endwhile;
```

The error I am getting is:

> Catchable fatal error: Object of class mysqli_result could not be
>   converted to string

Can anyone help me figuring out what the problem is?

Comment: are you getting error in " echo $details->country;"  ? if not then where you got this error , its like you are fething array and tri to print it with "echo" statement

Comment: try print_r($result_ip) and see what is in it

Comment: @amit mysqli_result Object ( [current_field] => 0 [field_count] => 1 [lengths] => [num_rows] => 24 [type] => 0 )

Comment: @BrijalSavaliya That was used as a test for myself removed it now

Comment: You are trying to fetch from `$details` but isn't `$ip` your mysql result? Can you `var_dump($details)`?

Comment: Is there any particular reason why you don't already have country info in the database?

Comment: fetch result from query result set "$result_ip"  there are 24 records you need to get any one IP from record set and pass it to http://ipinfo.io/{$ip}

Comment: @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams The database im using is an old one and already contains a lot of information, the moment it was made they didnt made it. made a copy of the database with only a few rows so i could see if the results we're true.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't use `mysqli_query` result directly. You need to fetch data from your query result

```
$result_ip = $dbhandle->query("SELECT ip FROM email");
$row_cnt_ip = $result_ip->num_rows;
$NL = array('');
$AL = array('');
$NO_EU = array('');

$row=$result_ip->fetch_assoc();// fetch data 
$ip=$row['ip'];

$details = json_decode(file_get_contents("http://ipinfo.io/{$ip}"));
```

Comment: Fatal error: Call to a member function fetch_array() on line, its the line where i start the while loop ill look into it now. Thanks for the answer looks like im one step closer now.

Comment: Use `$result_ip->data_seek(0); while($r = $result_ip->fetch_array(MYSQLI_ASSOC)):`

Comment: @Satly Thanks for your suggestion, the errors are going but if i print the $NL its giving me 552 results but there is only 24 rows in the database

Comment: gave you the answer getting really close with this now only have to figure out why its given me 552 results instead of 24